# Using JMX or SNPM4J with OpenJDK 8

Tags: java

I was searching the internet to finding some resources to use JMX or SNMP4J with OpenJDK 8. Can someone help with this?

With Oracle JDK 8 we used SNMP to send the Heap status to Nagios monitoring. SNMP is proprietary to Oracle JDK. This leads us to think about JMX or SNMP4J with OpenJDK 8.

Any support will be highly welcomed !!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up a couple of things.  The SNMP support in Java was an SNMP agent rather than a generic SNMP framework library (like SNMP4J).  And from what I can tell from looking at the OpenJDK source code:

- the SNMP agent was present in OpenJDK until at least OpenJDK 8, and
- it is not proprietary (according to the copyright headers).

Either way, SNMP support has been removed:

Bug tracker issue [JDK-820621](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8206211) says:

> "JVM-MANAGEMENT-MIB.mib was defined by JSR 163 / JSR 174 in Java SE 5 while the implementation is optional.  The implementation for JVM SNMP monitoring and management is provided by jdk.snmp module.  There has been nearly zero inquiry and bug issues w.r.t. SNMP monitoring support for JVM.  Due to the lack of customer usage, SNMP monitoring support for JVM has been deprecated in JDK 10 and removed in JDK 11."

<sup>(My trawling of the source trees suggests that SNMP might have been removed from OpenJDK before Oracle JDK, but I might have missed something.  I am doing this rather crudely.)</sup>

---

I don't think there is much chance that you will find a direct replacement for the the Oracle / OpenJDK SNMP agent, for either Oracle JDK or OpenJDK in Java 11 or later.

You might be able to extract the code from (say) the OpenJDK 10 source tree and port it to a later version of Java.  But this might entail making your own custom OpenJDK builds.

But you certainly can use JMX to monitor an OpenJDK.  It should be the same as for an Oracle JDK:

- [Monitoring and Management Using JMX Technology](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/management/monitoring-and-management-using-jmx-technology.html)